# MegaCLI always returns blank output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, lsi, megaraid

This server is a Dell R200 running Ubuntu 8.04LTS using a LSI SAS1068E raid card supplied from Dell, I suspect that there might be some kind of RAID issue with the hardware raid built into the motherboard, but I can't seem to get MegaCLi to return any useful output:

```
root@81 $ ./MegaCli -AdpAllInfo -aALL

root@81 $ ./MegaCli -PDList -aALL

root@81 $
```

The disks work and AFAIK the raid software is installed correctly. I've seen this issue on RedHat issues also in the past. The RAID was initially setup through the BIOS on this server and appears to be functioning fine apart from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAS1068E is closer to a "fake" firmware RAID controller than a "real" controller.  MegaCLI is designed only for "real" controllers.

According to [this thread on a Dell mailing list](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2009-March/038758.html), there are two alternatives:

1. [mpt-status](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=&q=mpt-status), an open-source utility, or
2. [lsiutil](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2009-March/038764.html), provided by LSI

Answer (score 1):

quick answer... do not mix pears and apples :)

- MegaCli and MegaCli64 are the binaries to "talk" to 2nd gen PCIe HW RAID LSI HBAs (LSI MegaRAID SAS 9262-8i)
- SAS2IRCU, is the one to be used with LSI SAS 2008 chipset (also 2nd gen).

If your machine is equipped with a LSI SAS 1068E, then it's a first gen PCIe device (3Gbps) and of course, can't "talk" via MegaCli... you must use alternate binaries to do that job, depending on your OS.

Of course, I'll recommend you to use "LSI MSM" bundle (I think LSI no longer exists, and the repos should be now maintained by Broadcom), or you can also use the card's BIOS (can be invoked during POST).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The RAID controller you are refering to is considered as being a fake RAID controller (source: Dell employees).

MegaCLI is only built for "real" RAID controllers, therefore you will receive no useful output from this tool. I recommend mpt-status for LSI controllers: http://freecode.com/projects/mptstatus

By the way:
"How can I differ 'fake' RAID controllers from normal ones?"
Normally, the price of "real" RAID controllers starts at 150 Euro, while "fake" are cheaper. There is no real border (150), but that value is based on my experience.

And you can look the model series up in the internet (besides by asking your hardware supplyer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed a 3.x.x linux kernel on that? Most versions of MegaCLI I have seen are broken with it because they mistake it for a 2.4.x and try using long obsolete interfaces.

Comment: For example, MegaCLI WILL NOT WORK from a knoppix CD (3.x.x kernel)  (tried to because I prefer to update RAID controller firmware to newest stable before installing an OS) with a 9260, which is an even harderware RAID controller ;)